# Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP with Qt Creator for C++11

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, c++11, qt-creator

How to use Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP in Qt Creator? 
And how to configure Qt library to that kind of usage? I need C++11 features like initialization lists.

I khow how to set up CTP compiler for VS2012. But how to invoke it from command line...

For Qt, maybe it can be configured through qmake-spec for CTP compiler?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the new compiler binaries to PATH from within a VS command prompt. Alternatively, you can point Qt Creator to the compiler binary `cl.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, you should install Visual Studio 2012 (the compiler is no more distributed alone)
2. Then, install Visual Studio 2012 November CTP
3. And finally, see my answer here: [How to use QTcreator with the Visual Studios november CTP compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085785/how-to-use-qtcreator-with-the-visual-studios-november-ctp-compiler)

I am able to use Qt 5.2.1 binaries (x86 and amd64) for VS2012 downloaded from qt-project.org.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in options, category "Build&Run", tab "Compilers". May be autodetection of this compiler fails, but nothing prevents to add it manually.